# solving a linear equation in the integers

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find the general solution in two variables of:

$5x+7y+9z=11$ in the integers, so I define a new variable $t=x+y+z$ so this becomes:

$5t+2y+4z=11$ and again define a new variable $u=y+2t+2z$ so that this becomes:

$t+2u=11$

I am now unsure as to how to proceed?

Comment: I am not sure where you are trying to go with this. I mean, I could also define $t = 5x + 7y + 9z$ to get the equation $t = 11$ but that doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done. Eliminating $\,t\,$ by back-substitution yields the general solution

$$\begin{eqnarray} x  &\,=\,& \ \ \ 33\,+\,z\,-\,7u\\ y &\,=\,& -22-2z+5u\end{eqnarray} $$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\gcd(5,7)=\gcd(5,9)=\gcd(7,9)=1$, there will be infinitely many solutions using any two of the variables alone.  Are you trying to find all of them, or just one?

Assuming you want all of them:

Let $z$ be arbitrary.  We want to find $x,y$ satisfying $5x+7y=(11-9z)$.  We may take $x=3(11-9z)+7k, y=-2(11-9z)-5k$, for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I am trying to find the general solution in two variables, I've edited it now

Comment: where did these solutions come from? where do the -2 and 3 come from?

Comment: $3\cdot 5 -2 \cdot 7 =1$, a minimal solution to Bezout's identity.

Comment: ok, thanks- does this work for all 3 variable linear equations in the integers?

Comment: Not this nicely, if the coefficients aren't pairwise relatively prime, there are some tweaks.

Comment: @user73957 There aren't really much tweaks. Either there are infinitely many solutions, or they are none. You proceed as Vadim123 laid out, and at the last step you will see if you can get integer solutions or not.

Comment: @CalvinLin so for example $2x+6y+9z=8$ we would have a solution $x=-4(8-6y)-9k$ and $y=(8-6y)-2k$ but we can't do this in terms of the other variables as we cant solve $2x+6y=1$?

Comment: @user73957: right.  If $z$ is even, you can solve $2x+6y=8-9z$, but not if $z$ is odd.